# have a form created for user input with add to cart button but not able to get product accordigly

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Practice page</title>
</head>
<div>
   <select id="height">
      <option value="select">Select</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="18">18</option>
      <option value="22">22</option>
      <option value="26">26</option>
      <option value="custom">custom</option>   
    </select>
<br/>
<select id="width">
    <option value="select">Select</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="36">36</option>
    <option value="42">42</option>
    <option value="custom">custom</option>    
 </select>
<button onClick="GetSelectedItem('width','height');">Add to cart </button>
</div>
<p id="getty"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function GetSelectedItem(el,gl)
{
  var e = document.getElementById(gl);
  var h = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value
  var e1 = document.getElementById(el);
  var w = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].value
  //no idea how should i connect it with available product in magento they have custom attribute (height & width ) with attribute set //
}                         
</script>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of Magento?

Comment: Magento 1.9 I know it would be connected via custom attribute value but not getting a proper way to do that plz help !!